# PHP date and time function wont store in the database

Tags: php, mysql, database, datetime, date

the date in the Database has a field of time which you can insert a date and a time but why is it that it is not being stored all I get is 0's when I check the database, but the other datas are being stored

here's my code

```
<?php 

session_start(); 
include("Connection.php");
    if (isset($_POST['submit']))  
    $name = $_POST['customerName'];


    $mysqldate = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' );
    $phpdate = strtotime( $mysqldate );

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO  `starbucks`.`orders` (
`ID` ,
`NAME` ,
`TOTAL_PRICE` ,
`TOTAL_ITEMS` ,
`TIME`
)
VALUES (
'' ,  '$name',  '', '','$phpdate')")  or die(mysql_error());

    $_SESSION['user'] = $name; 
    ?>
```

Comment: What type is your date field?

Comment: Might be a problem with the type of your date field named 'TIME'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use your $mysqldate instead of $phpdate

mysql_query("INSERT INTO  `starbucks`.`orders` (
`ID` ,
`NAME` ,
`TOTAL_PRICE` ,
`TOTAL_ITEMS` ,
`TIME`
)
VALUES (
'' ,  '$name',  '', '','$mysqldate')")  or die(mysql_error());

Comment: I did that but I received this error 
Notice: Undefined variable: mysqldate in C:\xampp\htdocs\Self Exercise\proj\order.php on line 10

Comment: i wonder why? make sure you add this on your code : $mysqldate = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' );

Answer (score 2):

`DATETIME` field is a date field, not a timestamp field.

The format is `date('Y-m-d H:i:s')`.

Answer (score 1):

if you are simply trying to add the current time, you don't need to create a timestamp in php but you can use NOW() in mysql instead

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO  `starbucks`.`orders` (
`ID` ,
`NAME` ,
`TOTAL_PRICE` ,
`TOTAL_ITEMS` ,
`TIME`
)
VALUES (
'' ,  '$name',  '', '',NOW())")
```